# Search for related properties in the same object. Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

I need help with matching childrens in the same object based on parent ID property....

JSON:

```
{
"1": {
"id": 1,
"name": "My Crib",
"type": "Home",
"order": 0,
"parent": null
},
"2": {
"id": 2,
"name": "First floor",
"type": "Floor",
"order": 1,
"parent": {
"id": 1,
"url": "http://localhost:8080/rest/areas/1"
}
},
"3": {
"id": 3,
"name": "Garage",
"type": "Garage",
"order": 2,
"parent": {
"id": 1,
"url": "http://localhost:8080/rest/areas/1"
}
},
"4": {
"id": 4,
"name": "Garden",
"type": "Garden",
"order": 3,
"parent": {
"id": 1,
"url": "http://localhost:8080/rest/areas/1"
}
},
"5": {
"id": 5,
"name": "Entrance hall",
"type": "Entrance",
"order": 1,
"parent": {
"id": 2,
"url": "http://localhost:8080/rest/areas/2"
}
},
"6": {
"id": 6,
"name": "Kitchen",
"type": "Kitchen",
"order": 2,
"parent": {
"id": 2,
"url": "http://localhost:8080/rest/areas/2"
}
},
"7": {
"id": 7,
"name": "Living room",
"type": "LivingRoom",
"order": 3,
"parent": {
"id": 2,
"url": "http://localhost:8080/rest/areas/2"
}
},
"8": {
"id": 8,
"name": "Dog house",
"type": "DogHouse",
"order": 1,
"parent": {
"id": 4,
"url": "http://localhost:8080/rest/areas/4"
}
}
}

const mappedAreas = Object.keys(areas).map(function(key) {
  const area = areas[key];
  const wrappers = statics["test.area.groups"]["wrappers"];
  const leafs = statics["test.area.groups"]["leafs"];

  if (wrappers.indexOf(area["type"]) > -1) {
      //In the array!

      //If not a home
      if(area["type"] != "Home"){
        console.log("floor:")
        console.log(area)

        //get wrapper childrens
        const children = Object.keys(areas).map(function(key) {
          const child = areas[key];

          if(child["type"] != "Home"){
            if(child["parent"]["id"] == area["id"] && leafs.indexOf(child["type"]) > -1){
              console.log(child);
              //return <Area key={"area_index_"+key} areaData={area} />
            }
          }
        });
        console.log("endfloor/")
        //return <Area key={"area_index_"+key} areaData={area} />
      }
  } else {
      //Not in the array

  }
});
```

Is there any way to do this better than having one map inside another map?

Basicly I get all areas in one object, and I want to match them with eachother, looking for ["parent"]["id"] to match with ["id"].

Tell me if you need more description.

Comment: It's a little bit unclear what your asking, maybe an example of what your sending to `areas` might help.

Comment: Hi @Keith I updated firstpost with the JSON. Areas contains the JSON above.

Comment: And I want to be able to match those with eachother to get childrens if the area doesnt match with the ["wrappers"]. Added some comments to the code.

Comment: please add a wanted result.

Comment: @NinaScholz Wanted result is to be able to get a variable with each parent ( that matches with ["wrappers"]) and children related to that parent in each loop.

Comment: @NinaScholz I updated firstpost with a working example. My question now is if there's a better way to do it.